# run single animation on multiple touches

Tags: iphone, xcode

all

I am facing one problem the problem is that I want to hit an object infinite time and it show me the animation only once.. how can I do it.. plz give me an idea of this

code

ccTouches Function

```
if(firstValue >= 125 && sencndvalu <=138)
        {
            if(multipleTouch == 0)
            {   
                [self FaceAni:@"chammat.plist"];
            }
            multipleTouch ++;

            if(multipleTouch > 2)
                [self fallingAnimation:@"fallingNew.plist"]; 
        }
```

}

-(void)FaceAni:(NSString *)plistFile 
{

```
multipleTouch = 0;

animationIsOn = 1;

[self removebackgroundTexture];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:plistFile];        

NSString *changeFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", plistFile];

changeFileName = [changeFileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".plist" withString:@".png"];

spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:changeFileName];

[self addChild:spriteSheet];

// Load up the frames of our animation
walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) 
{ 
    if(i <= 9)
    {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chmaat_0000%d.png", i]]];
    }
    else
    {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chmaat_000%d.png", i]]];
    }
}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.10f];

// Create a sprite for our bear
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Chmaat_00000.png"];      

_bear.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 230);

self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
//[_bear runAction:_walkAction];
[spriteSheet addChild:_bear];
[_bear runAction:_walkAction];
```

//  [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playEffect:@"slap3.wav"];

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeFrame) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

}

Comment: What type of animation u are trying to achieve. If possible provide the code u are working for better understanding.

Comment: @imasuld see the above code,, thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- set a Boolean flag that is initiated with a value of YES
- in your method that runs the animation, check the status of that Boolean flag. If YES, run your animation
- then have that method set the flag to NO.

The first time the animation is shown the flag will be set to NO and the animation won't run again.

Comment: I want to run the animation as you can see in the talking tom type app

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question.Use a thread method to run the animation and check the thread, if the thread is not working do the animation.
The code will be like this,

```
- (void)waitForSoundDriverThreadToFinish {
    while (soundPlayerThread && ![soundPlayerThread isFinished]) { // Wait for the thread to finish.
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
}


- (void)startDriverThread {
    if (soundPlayerThread != nil) {
        [soundPlayerThread cancel];
        [self waitForSoundDriverThreadToFinish];
    }

    NSThread *driverThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startDriverTimer:) object:nil];
    self.soundPlayerThread = driverThread;
    [driverThread release];

    [self.soundPlayerThread start];
}


- (void)stopDriverThread {
    [self.soundPlayerThread cancel];
    [self waitForSoundDriverThreadToFinish];
    self.soundPlayerThread = nil;
}
```

This code is from the Metronome sample code